# QueryforList result show table name

Tags: java, sql, spring, jdbctemplate

I use springjdbctemplate to query data from hive database.

This is my code:

```
@RestController
public class QueryController {
    @Autowired
    protected JdbcTemplate hiveTemplate;

    @RequestMapping("/query")
    public List query() {
        List data = hiveTemplate.queryForList("select * from ecg.hivetbluserdata limit 100");
        return data;
    }
}
```

But it returns this:

```
[{"hivetbluserdata.id_data":1,"hivetbluserdata.id_user":1,"hivetbluserdata.time":"Thursday, April 09, 2015 18:09:26","hivetbluserdata.ecgvalue":3.3871,"hivetbluserdata.inputtime":"2015-04-09 18:11:25.0"},
{"hivetbluserdata.id_data":2,"hivetbluserdata.id_user":1,"hivetbluserdata.time":"Thursday, April 09, 2015 18:09:26","hivetbluserdata.ecgvalue":1.56892,"hivetbluserdata.inputtime":"2015-04-09 18:11:25.0"},
{"hivetbluserdata.id_data":3,"hivetbluserdata.id_user":1,"hivetbluserdata.time":"Thursday, April 09, 2015 18:09:26","hivetbluserdata.ecgvalue":1.60802,"hivetbluserdata.inputtime":"2015-04-09 18:11:26.0"},
{"hivetbluserdata.id_data":4,"hivetbluserdata.id_user":1,"hivetbluserdata.time":"Thursday, April 09, 2015 18:09:26","hivetbluserdata.ecgvalue":2.09677,"hivetbluserdata.inputtime":"2015-04-09 18:11:26.0"},
{"hivetbluserdata.id_data":5,"hivetbluserdata.id_user":1,"hivetbluserdata.time":"Thursday, April 09, 2015 18:09:26","hivetbluserdata.ecgvalue":1.99902,"hivetbluserdata.inputtime":"2015-04-09 18:11:26.0"},
{"hivetbluserdata.id_data":6,"hivetbluserdata.id_user":1,"hivetbluserdata.time":"Thursday, April 09, 2015 18:09:26","hivetbluserdata.ecgvalue":1.97947,"hivetbluserdata.inputtime":"2015-04-09 18:11:26.0"},
{"hivetbluserdata.id_data":7,"hivetbluserdata.id_user":1,"hivetbluserdata.time":"Thursday, April 09, 2015 18:09:26","hivetbluserdata.ecgvalue":1.94037,"hivetbluserdata.inputtime":"2015-04-09 18:11:26.0"},
{"hivetbluserdata.id_data":8,"hivetbluserdata.id_user":1,"hivetbluserdata.time":"Thursday, April 09, 2015 18:09:27","hivetbluserdata.ecgvalue":1.56892,"hivetbluserdata.inputtime":"2015-04-09 18:11:26.0"},
```

I don't want to show the table name (`hivetbluserdata` is the table name). How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Haven't seen that before, but try giving an alias for the qualified table name, e.g. `"select u.* from ecg.hivetbluserdata u limit 100"`. FYI: You should never use `*` in your code. Always list the columns you are interested in. `*` is nice shorthand for ad-hoc queries, but since your code is interested in specific columns, it should list those columns, even if they are (currently) all the columns of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following Hive configuration property to disable table names in the result set:

```
<property>
   <name>hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names</name>
   <value>false</value>
</property>
```

Reference:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties#ConfigurationProperties-hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names

> **hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names**
>
> Default Value: true
>
> Added In: Hive 0.13.0 with HIVE-6687
>
> Make column names unique in the result set
> by qualifying column names with table alias if needed. Table alias
> will be added to column names for queries of type "select *" or if
> query explicitly uses table alias "select r1.x..".